# В описании тревоги 'вопрос должен быть закрыт' неправильная ссылка

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, причины-закрытия

На данный момент выглядит так:

> Данный вопрос является совсем непонятным, неполным, слишком общим,
>   основанным на личном мнение или не относится к теме Stack Overflow на
>   русском как описано в [Справке] (/help/on-topic) и вероятно не
>   подвергался правкам.

Полагаю, что там должна быть ссылка на **Справку** (т.е [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help)), но ее нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за замечание! Проблема была в пробеле межу скобками "]" и "(" в переводе. Поправил. Исправленный перевод будет доступен в ближайшей сборке движка.